# Linq to hibernate common function

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-entities

Is there a way to somehow encapsulate repeated projection methods like this one:
I have Subject entity which has properties title_before, title_after, first_name, surname. Now i need to repeat concatening of strings to get Name of subject in every linq expression. I would like to refactor it to something like Expression function or something, so i just call GetName() on my entity and it gets traslated to sql. Is this possible? Maybe its not just nhibernate but linq to entities too.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: Do you need to do this on the db side? If not just have a property on the object you project into that is Name and define it as the first name and surname. If you need it on the db side create a derived column Name on you table and map it to to a Name property on the object.

Comment: Im not allowed to do any logic on db side

Comment: Do you need to? Are you doing anything with this that has to happen on the database or just retrieving and displaying it?

Comment: just displaying data

Comment: This (https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/lesser-known-nhibernate-features-linq-extensions) might be worth exploring if you need the performance benefits of doing as part of the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to display it you can just do it with a property

```
public class OriginalClass
{
     public string first_name { get; set; }
     public string surname { get; set; }

     // other properties
}
```

Then your target class

```
public class TargetClass
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name => $"{FirstName} {Surname}";
}
```

Then project into it with select

```
var results = context.OriginalClasses.Select(
   oc => new TargetClass
   {
       FirstName = oc.first_name,
       Surname = os.surname,
   });
```

Then when displaying just reference Name and you will get the value. Just don't use it in an expression against an IQueryable as it has no database mapping.

If you have a bunch of classes you are projecting into you could make an IHaveName interface and write a GetName() extension method against it.

Comment: I would like to not want to retrieve all the extra fields (its not just firstname surname, there are 5 of them, also i need to do isnull on them) then convert to ienumarable. I would like a common function which gets expanded to expression that executes in sql server. Im asking if there is way to not dry.

Comment: Can you edit your question to say what you actually want to ask with some example code? I can only the answer the question you asked, not read your mind. It maybe you want a mapping tool to define you projection once and reuse it but I can't tell.